# How to add onload in input element on dynamic form

Tags: javascript, html

I bullied dynamic form. when clicking on task in table with javascript I create call for api that get html form that written to page with .intterhtml
I tried to run function when specific input load
input code:

```
<input disabled placeholder='some text' onload="functionName('text')">
```

How can I do it if the input loaded after page loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the other way round using Jquery which would be convenient:

```
**HTML:**
<input disabled placeholder='some text' id="txtName">

**Script:**
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('txtName').on('load', function(){
     $(this).text('text');
   });
 });
</script>
```